# Logitech F710 to run teleop for turtlebot3

Tags: ubuntu, ros

I have a Logitech F710 controller that i want it to run a teleop on my turtlebot3, however whenever i launch the teleop_twist_joy, it seems like it is always in the default settings and following a tutorial on wiki.ros (https://github.com/SMARTlab-Purdue/ros-tutorial-robot-control-vision/wiki/Robot-control-with-Joystick) to perform a configuration, but after configuration it seems like it is always in the default. Please advice on how i can setup my joystick so that i can use it to run a simulation in gazebo

Comment: Please provide more details of what you have tried and how you are changing the 'configuration' and what you mean by default.

Comment: Hi Vik, i have tried to use $ sudo jstest /dev/input/js2 and once i knew the controller is working, i then use $ rosparam set /dev/input/ "/dev/input/js2" but when i run a $ roslaunch turtlebot_teleop_twist_joy teleop.launch, it show that the parameters is still in the default js0 and not what i set at start

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because the launch file  is setting it to the default value. Try launching it as

```
roslaunch teleop_twist_joy teleop.launch joy_dev:="/dev/input/js2" joy_config:="atk3"
```

or

```
roslaunch teleop_twist_joy teleop.launch joy_dev:="/dev/input/js2" joy_config:="xd3"
```

Comment: Hi Vik, also i am facing an error of "Couldnt open force feedback" when launching the teleop_twist_joy, i believe it might be a condition that is not fulfiled when this file is launch.

Comment: Hi vik, yes it works without the feedback. But what might be the issue here?

Comment: Looks like the launch file defaults to the ps3 config file, you can try the above commands using the joy_config parameters as updated above.
Also, there is a possibility that feedback is not yet available on your controller model as described here - https://github.com/ros-drivers/joystick_drivers/pull/111